# Error Message on Link Click in Chakra UI React App

Tags: reactjs, chakra-ui

I'm currently building a frontend using Chakra UI in React. I have successfully integrated the backend and data is being fetched correctly. However, when I click on a Link to navigate, an error message appears. Interestingly, the functionality works fine if I refresh the page or manually enter the URL in the address bar. The error only occurs when I click on specific links like the home link button or photo category link button. The error message indicates that it's the same issue I had resolved before, but it keeps appearing. How can I resolve this problem?

```
export default function LookAround() {
    const gray = useColorModeValue("gray.600", "gray.300")
    const { isLoading, data } = useQuery<{ photos: IHome[]; texts: IHome[]; videos: IHome[] }>(
    ["photos"],
    HomeLook
    );
    
    if (isLoading) {
        return <div>Loading...</div>; // 로딩 중일 때 표시할 UI
    }
    
    if (!data) {
    return <div>No data available</div>; // 데이터가 없을 때 표시할 UI
    }

    
    return (
        <>

        <VStack>
            <Box w="100%">
                <Link to={"/api/v1/photos"}>
                    <HStack alignItems={"flex-start"} ml={16} mt={8} mb={6}>
                        <Text color={gray} fontWeight={"bold"} fontSize={24}>사진 둘러보기</Text>
                        <IconButton color={gray} fontSize={20} aria-label="more follower's photos" variant={"unstyled"} icon={<FaAngleDoubleRight />} disabled={isLoading} />
                    </HStack>
                </Link>
            </Box>
            

            <Box mr={10} pl={14} w="100%" h="35rem" overflow={"auto"} overflowX={"scroll"} css={{'&::-webkit-scrollbar': { display:"none"}}}>
                <Grid gap={10} gridAutoFlow={"column"} gridTemplateColumns="repeat(6, 1fr)" gridTemplateRows="repeat(2, 1fr)">
                {data.photos.slice(0, 14).map((home) => (
                <LookHomePhoto photo={home.photo} pk={home.pk} key={home.pk} /> // photo와 pk prop을 전달
                ))}
                </Grid>
            </Box>
```

```
interface IPhotoProps {
    photo: string;
    pk:number;
}

const LookHomePhoto: React.FC<IPhotoProps> = ({ photo, pk }) =>{
    return (
        <>
        <Link to={`api/v1/photos/${pk}`}>
            <Box w={60} h={60} backgroundColor="gray">
                <Image objectFit={"cover"} w={60} h={60} src={photo}/>
            </Box>
        </Link>
            
        </>
    )
}

export default LookHomePhoto;
```

it shows me "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'slice')" error message. but i think i solved it.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with Chakra, you have an error from JavaScript because `data.photos` is probably undefined. add `console.log(data.photos)` you should get undefined.

Add this to your code to fix the issue:

```
if (!data || !data.photos) {
    return <div>No data available</div>;
}
```